# How to create an "Items" property for my control?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, custom-controls

How can I create an "Items" property for my control in C#? I want an "Items" property like "Items" property of "ComboBox" or "ListBox" controls that you enter items line by line and just the text of each line is important for you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you derive your UC from ListBox, for example, like that:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : ListBox
```